# How do I do "Edit and Continue" builds with cmake projects in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I want to do "Edit and Continue" in my Visual studio cmake C++ projects.
I know I have to change /Zi to /ZI, but where?

This is C++

Answer (score 1):

The options must be set as follows:

```
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG: /MDd /ZI /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG: /MDd /ZI /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG: /debug /INCREMENTAL /LTCG:OFF
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG: /debug /INCREMENTAL /LTCG:OFF
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG: /debug /INCREMENTAL /LTCG:OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

I found answer in Microsoft Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170):

```
if(MSVC)
   target_compile_options(<target> PUBLIC "/ZI")
   target_link_options(<target> PUBLIC "/INCREMENTAL")
endif()
```

Also you may want to do it globally like:

```
# if you what to use MSVC Edit And Continue (uncomment below, reconfigure)
# And go to Debug->Options->Debugging->General and on right panel
# set check to Enable Edit and Continue
if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options("/ZI")
    add_link_options("/INCREMENTAL")
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to insert the following commands before the definition of your first target:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/ZI")
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "/SAFESEH:NO")
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "/SAFESEH:NO")
endif()
```

If you prefer to set the options for a specific target, use

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
  target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "/ZI")
  target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "/SAFESEH:NO")
endif()
```

Warning: as of the latest version of Visual Studio at the time of writing (16.4.2), Visual Studio cannot deal with changes to lambda functions.

Comment: How do you do this for debug build only?

Comment: This overrides the value of CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG, which may not be the intended result; to append the value instead, do
    `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /ZI")`

Comment: @PedroVicente It is recommended to prefer `list(APPEND listVar item [item...])` over `set(listVar "${listVar} /ZI")` according to the Book https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/